# Calculate the potential difference for each capacitor (problem)

Tags: homework

Below we have an AC circuit with diodes connected in parallel and a few capacitors in between. Von=1V and Ron=0 for each diode. I am asked to find the potential for each of the capacitors when sufficient time has passed after the switch was closed.

[image]

The signal vi is shown in the graph below.

[image]

I understand that I can replace the diodes with equivalent 1 V voltage sources and solve the circuit accordingly but there's 2 things that are confusing to me:

1. Since an ac signal is fed into the circuit, vi changes with time. How should I choose the voltage vi to analyze the circuit?
2. Charge is not given in the problem, what am I supposed to do with the capacitances?

By the way, the answers are v1=9V,v2=18V,v3=18V

Comment: The diodes can be assumed to be reversed 1V sources but only when the diode is forward biased. When a diode is reverse biased (or below the 1V approximation) they can assume to be open. You could analyze the component voltages in sections ideally at each AC wave peak, (+/-).  In a basic approximation assume that the capacitors pass AC current but block DC current.  Last hint, DC charges will accumulate on each capacitor due to the diodes, AC peaks will temporarily add or subtract to/from the capacitor charges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since an AC signal is fed into the circuit, **v**<sub>***i***</sub>
> changes with time. How should I choose the voltage
> **v**<sub>***i***</sub> to analyze the circuit?

If you're not specifically asked to figure out the initial voltages at specific points in time (before they charge up the capacitors), then the peak voltages of the sine wave are used.

> I am asked to find the potential for each of the capacitors when
> sufficient time has passed after the switch was closed.

This answers your question: they're not asking for voltages at specific points in time, but merely "when sufficient time has passed after the switch was closed", meaning when all capacitors are fully charged.

> Charge is not given in the problem, what am I supposed to do with the
> capacitances?

Charge is not given, but neither is the voltage source current or impedance, meaning that you can assume it sufficient to immediately charge a capacitor. 
So, you're basically asked to figure out the principle of a capacitor-diode multiplier, and are given simple assumptions to make it easier to calculate. 
[image]
[image]

Since graph shows peak voltage of 10V, we start with the first capacitor and a positive half-cycle to charge it. 
This would charge the first capacitor (v<sub>1</sub>) to 10-1=9V. The positive ends of the capacitors are in the same direction as the arrows below them. 
The negative half-cycle will add 10V in series to the v<sub>1</sub>, making it a total of 19V which will appear across the second capacitor MINUS 1V second diode drop, making v<sub>2</sub> charged to 18V. 
The second positive half-cycle will add 10V to the 18V on v<sub>2</sub> for a total of 28V appearing on its other end MINUS the 1V diode drop and v<sub>1</sub> voltage of 9V, giving 18V across v<sub>3</sub> and 27V in total from the lower end of the voltage source to the positive side of the 3rd capacitor. 
So, you got it right: v<sub>1</sub> will be 9V, v<sub>2</sub> will be 18V, and v<sub>3</sub> will also be 18V.

[image]

The image may be a little confusing. The red voltages are for positive half-cycle, blue voltages are negative half-cycle, in green are the final voltages.